# How to recover BitLocker encrypted partition that is now 'unallocated'/'free space'?

Tags: bitlocker, partition-recovery

My hard drive had five partitions, including one some 4-5 GB BitLocker encrypted one. When I used `Disk Management` I could view two partitions (24.4 GB and 8.94 GB) in green colour labelled Empty space.

So, I wanted to merge them and I used MiniTool partition wizard for the purpose. I don't know what that software did, but all I was left with was two partitions and lots of green free space.

I recovered two partitions using EaseUS partition master, but the BitLocker encrypted partition cannot be searched by it, nor by MiniTool partition recovery.

Now, the `Disk Management` shows a free space partition and an unallocated partition, of 28.36 GB and 8.94 GB, respectively.  Here is a screenshot:

[image: Disk Management]

Please, tell me a way to recover the BitLocker-encrypted partition that is showing as a free space in `Disk Management`.

Answer (score 2):

BitLocker cannot be recovered without the certificate created with it, and the data currently in tact. That's part of their security.

Comment: So, wouldn't it work even if I have the recovery key??

Comment: You would need an exact image of the data to apply the key to

Comment: Chances of recovery occur bleak now.

Will Microsoft support be of some help?

Comment: Just to tell you to backup next time, or don't touch partitions

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that only the volume header was lost (as opposed to the volume contents) you may be able to reconstruct the volume. The critical info, the actual BL headers, isn't stored at the start of the partition. However, the offsets of those BL headers (they are replicated a few times) are stored in the volume header. You'll need to find them again in order to reconstruct the header. Fortunately, they start with a distinctive "magic number" - the string `-FVE-FS-` that you can scan the partition for. You can try resurrecting your volume using the on-disk structure layout described here: https://github.com/Aorimn/dislocker/blob/master/src/metadata/metadata.h. Note that it's incomplete, so you may need to cross-reference with other BL drives to figure out the expected values. I was able to repair a damaged BL volume, with the help of this information, using a hex editor in a Linux LiveCD.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is [M3 Bitlocker Recovery Free](http://www.m3datarecovery.com/bitlocker-drive-data-recovery/) that is a commercial software. In the free version you can recover only 100MB of your lost data.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Hasleo Data Recovery, a professional data recovery software which allows you to recover data from accidentally formatted or deleted BitLocker encrypted drive. Unfortunately, it is also a commercial software.