# How to restore deleted/formatted Bitlocker encrypted partitions/ partition tables

Tags: windows-8.1, partitioning, 64-bit, bitlocker

Initially I had 2TB Seagate Expansion Desk HDD,  partitioned into 500GB, 13GB, 500GB, all three Bitlocker encrypted and 1 more 500GB unencrypted partition,  the rest of the space was unallocated.  Yesterday,  by mistake, while I was creating Windows Recovery Disk chose the wrong drive letter and ended up whole partitions above deleted. Here's what I have in HDD now: 32GB Windows 8 Recovery partition and 1831GB unallocated space. 
After that I haven't made any changes to the drive.  I was able to restore the data from the last unencrypted part by using Getdataback SW but with no luck in my Bitlocker encrypted partitions.  I would appreciate any advice to restore the bitlockerencrypted partitions as I have the password to decrypt and retrieve my data back. Thank you, Super Users.

Softwares at hand:
Recuva. Handy Recovery.  R-Studio.  Getdataback. M3 Bitlocker Recovery. Starus Partition Recovery. TestDisk

[How to recover BitLocker encrypted partition that is now 'unallocated'/'free space'?](https://superuser.com/questions/429288/how-to-recover-bitlocker-encrypted-partition-that-is-now-unallocated-free-spa)

Comment: You may be able to undelete the 13 GB and the 2nd 500 GB partition using demo of DMDE.

Comment: That first 500 will be hardest as it got partially overwritten. The other 3 should be undeletable. Can you post a DMDE partition tab screenshot (see: https://youtu.be/XGDcQTPuubs)?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [at this article](http://www.normanbauer.com/2013/07/25/how-to-recover-data-from-a-deleted-bitlocker-enabled-partition/) as this is the closest I could find that makes halfway sense. Should be a little bit tricky in your case as you had multiple encrypted partitions. Also read [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/4c323863-8962-4cbf-ae2b-aeeddb285544/how-to-recover-a-deleted-bitlocker-encrypted-partition?forum=w7itprosecurity) for background information purposes before starting with anything.

Comment: Thank very much,  Bernd.  The article looks promising to me. But I could not start the process yet.  I am confused what to do first.  Do I need to delete newly created Windows Recovery partition and make the whole 2TB space unallocated and start creating new partitions with a similar size to my lost bitlocker partitions without actually formatting them and then proceed to repair-bde part? I also need to mention that I only know the password to bitlocker, not the key.

Comment: I am afraid you need the recovery key otherwise this will not work. I presume this computer is not joined to a domain so can you recall if you saved the key to file or maybe saved it even with your live account (e.g. is a option with Windows 8)?

Comment: Hello. I have found my recovery keys in my Skydrive folder. Do you think the keys contain any information about the partition?  And is there any way to extract that info (e.g. hex viewer or something like that) to use while reallocatiting the partitions back? I mean the exact size and starting points of the partitions. Can I also proceed deleting the current Windows Recovery volume because only then I can allocate the space for repair-bde. I'm trying not do any further damage to my HDD. Thank you for the time and effort.

Comment: Nope - the recovery key only has the recovery key, key ID, upload date of the key and drive type (e.g removable drive, operating system drive, etc.). You could a third-party tool to find the lost partition like http://findandmount.com. I think the biggest challenge is to find a tool that is for free and gives you the info you need.